# VMware Workstation on Linux: Dropping core files in a shared folder

Tags: vmware-workstation, network-share

I'm using VMware 6.0.2 on a RHEL 4.6 host. The VMs are MontaVista CGE 5.0 (2.6.21 kernel). I'm trying to get applications running in the VMs to drop any core files on a HGFS volume, i.e. in a "shared folder". The core files get created as per the path and format given in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern, but they are always zero length. If I change the path to a local path (on a virtual disk in the VM), all is well.

Any ideas what I have to do get the core files written into a shared folder?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed the issue over here.  I don't know why Linux refuses to dump core contents to an HGFS share (Arch Linux kernel 2.6.32 with open-vm-tools 2010.01.19 here), but I do have a solution.

Linux 2.6.19 and higher will let you pipe core dumps through an arbitrary program, so create a shell script that copies its stdin to a file on your HGFS share, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Where do you want the core to go?
COREFILE=/mnt/hgfs/vmshare/core

tee $COREFILE >/dev/null
```

Of course you may wish to implement some logic for `$COREFILE` so that each subsequent core dump doesn't just overwrite the last.

Save your script as `/usr/local/bin/core.sh`, then set the file's executable bit and configure core_pattern as follows:

```
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/core.sh
# sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='|/usr/local/bin/core.sh'
```

Linux will pipe any core dumps through your shell script, which won't have any problem writing to the HGFS share itself.

If you're wondering, you can't simply put the `tee` command directly in kernel.core_pattern, because in kernels older than 2.6.24 you can't specify arguments to a pipe command with this sysctl.  For the same reason, unfortunately I can't think of a good way for you to incorporate the core_pattern template specifiers into your core dump file names using this method, if you're tied to kernel 2.6.21.

Comment: +1 This is at least a step in the right direction! But, as you suspected, I have to use a core_pattern template w/ specifiers. Let me see if I can work with this approach. Thanks for your answer!